# how to get original string value from encrypted string?

Tags: java

I am encrypting password using `DigestUtils.sha256Hex("password")`.I get encrypted password as `5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8`

I want original password string from encrypted . How shall i get it?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: you don't want to. ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of Sha256 hashing is that you cannot decrypt it. When doing a login check, you should hash the user entered password and match it with the one you've stored in your datalayer.

Comment: +1. You should also only store a *salted* hash (something like `sha256Hex(salt+password)`. Otherwise any two users with the same password *in any system* get the the same hash and it becomes somewhat reversible using rainbow tables. For example, you can google 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8.

Answer (score 1):

`DigestUtils.sha256Hex` is not encription it is hash. Main property of hash it is irreversible